# My symfony 5.1 application does not send images with vichUpload

Tags: symfony5, vichuploaderbundle

I developed a note management application with **symfony 5.1** and I registered the students with their photos with **VichUpload **without problem.

Overnight, my application can no longer modify a student or add a new student because of **VichUplaod**.

Please can someone help me to solve the problem with VichUpload bundle or other bundle ?

Thank you for your lights.

To try to fix the problem, I installed the latest version of VichUpload again but without success.

What I want is to register the students with their photos with VichUpload or another bundle.